# Как правильно присваивать onclick-событие к элементам через цикл?

Tags: javascript

Код ниже при нажатии на любую кнопку выводит число `5`, а должен `0/1/2/3/4`.
Как заставить `onlick`-событие выводить конкретный номер итерации в цикле?

```
<button>log 1</button>
<button>log 2</button>
<button>log 3</button>
<button>log 4</button>
<button>log 5</button>

<script>
  var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
  for (var i = 0, len = buttons.length; i < len; i++) {
    buttons[i].onclick = function() {
      console.log(i);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: [Ответ на: почему всегда 5](https://learn.javascript.ru/closures#%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<button>log 1</button>
<button>log 2</button>
<button>log 3</button>
<button>log 4</button>
<button>log 5</button>

<script>
    foo();        
    function foo() {
        var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button") || [],
            i, len = buttons.length;            

        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            buttons[i].onclick = getStep(i);
        }
    }    
    function getStep(i) {
        return function () {
                console.log(i+1);
        }
    }
</script>
```